Prove the convergance value of a telescoping series
This is an infinite series of subsequent square roots ($6,7,8,...$) and multiplied coefficients ($1,2,3...$) in the front of each, which converges to $4$.
Is there a way algebraically to prove it? By say assigning it to a variable and applying an operation to both sides in order to cancel out the infinite part and resolving it? (Similar to what we do for repeating decimals).
Thanks
$$
1 \sqrt{6 + 
    2 \sqrt{7 + 
       3 \sqrt{8 + 
          4 \sqrt{9 + 
            5 \sqrt{10 + 
              6 \sqrt{11 + 
                7 \sqrt{12}}}}}}}
                    ...
$$

This looks similar to the Ramanujan Nested Root problem,
Here, if we assume $$f(x)=x(x+3)$$
$$f(x)=x\sqrt{(x+5)+f(x+1)}=x\sqrt{(x+5)+f(x+1)\sqrt{(x+6)+f(x+2)}}\;...$$
Putting $n=1$, we get that
$$
1 \sqrt{6 + 
    2 \sqrt{7 + 
       3 \sqrt{8 + 
          4 \sqrt{9 + 
            5 \sqrt{10 + 
              6 \sqrt{11 + 
                7 \sqrt{12}}}}}}}
                    ...
\;=\;4$$
I hope this was what you were looking for

Sure looks good, still trying to see how you went from the first line to the left of the second line...

Ok got the connection, just expand it and cancels with the root. Ok..
